# Characterization of non-isomorphic graphs but isomorphic total graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Given a graph $G$, the *total graph of $G$*, denoted $T(G)$, is the graph with vertex set $V(G) \cup E(G)$, where $a$ and $b$ are adjacent in $T(G)$ if and only if they are adjacent or incident in $G$.

> Is there any characterization of properties of two graphs $G$ and $H$ such that $T(G)$ is isomorphic to $T(H)$?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/229696/characterization-of-non-isomorphic-graphs-but-isomorphic-total-graphs/229722#229722

Comment: Since you got an answer on mathoverflow.net, you could mention this here in math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: That is what I provided the link